# Spring Boot 3, tomcat SizeLimitExceededException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am currently making a backend for my fileShare client, which is according to my plans would be something like onedrive or nextcloud in the end.
I am creating the backend in Spring Boot 3.1.4 under Java 17. I have made an entry point like this:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                             @RequestParam("isFolder") Boolean isFolder,
                                             @RequestParam("destFolder") String destFolder){
        try{
            Path path = fileAccessService.uploadFile(multipartFile, isFolder.booleanValue(), destFolder);
            if(path == null){
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("The file or folder already exists");
            }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("The upload was successful. The file has been uploaded to: " + path);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            log.error("There was an error while trying to transfer file to the server: " + ex.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
```

But whenever I try to test this using either my half done application or postman with a kinda large file (around 400kB) I get this exception:

`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (414187747) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)`

I have NOT configured this at all, so I am guessing this is a default value.

My question is how can I configure either tomcat or Spring Boot to accept (ideally) infintely large files.

P.S.: I have not installed tomcat spearately, I am running the program in IntelliJ's debugger, and planning to deploy it onto a Linux based server using maven (which server also doesn't have a tomcat installed separatelly). I already have other Spring Boot apps running on the said server.

My first atempt was to try and configure this from the properties file:
`server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=1000GB server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=1000GB`
Without any luck.

Comment: Set `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1`.